# How to correctly log into my ASP Web API from MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

Hi i have created a solution which contains a web-api 2.2 project in VS2013 and a MVC 5 project.

I am trying to login to the account saved on the DB that the web-api has access to. So i use the web-api address /token. Then i take the the bearer token and use the /UserInfo to get user info and return it to the MVC project.

I then use this info to store the user info into a custom IIdentity and IPrincipal. the problem is i have never made custom ones of these before and i am having trouble getting them to persist over controller and such.

I have made a basic example below of what am trying to do. In the example below i want to create logged on user when i hit the home page and then be able to access their data from any other controller or method. As you can in the default MVC project. Only diffrence is this MVC project does not have direct access to the DB but can only make calls to the web-api.

Hope i have explained this well enough.

Here is example below (problem is in example is that after clicking on the about method controller, the user data is lost from the index controller. I did expect this but do not know how to persist data for each user)

```
 public class CustomIdentity : IIdentity
    {
        public CustomIdentity(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public string AuthenticationType {
            get { return "Custom"; }
        }

        public bool IsAuthenticated
        {
            get
            {
                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty((this.Name));
            }
        }
    }


public class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
    {
        public CustomPrincipal(CustomIdentity identity, string[] roles)
        {
            Identity = identity;
            Roles = roles;
        }

        public bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            return Roles.Any(r => r == role);
        }

        public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }
        public string[] Roles { get; private set; }


    }


public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var identity = new CustomIdentity("bob");
            var principal = new CustomPrincipal(identity, new []{"admin", "USER"});
            HttpContext.User = principal;
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            ViewBag.User = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
            ViewBag.User = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            ViewBag.User = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: follow this tutorial http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/ where baseapicontroller is used for login, and all api controllers derives this one, or the login process: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: Am sorry you misunderstand. My webapi is fine, i just need my mvc project to login and remember the user details after login. So i can call it up in other methods